# Debugging webOS TV service

Tags: debugging, service, webos

I'm currently developing a **webOS TV application** which includes a background running service. I'm having trouble getting logs to print in the NodeJS console.
I have no prior experience working with Node so I'm unsure whether any additional modules are required to get this done(but I highly doubt it, and the docs don't seem to suggest so.)

As of now my service side code is as follows;

```
var Service = require('webos-service');
var service = new Service("com.nuwan.helloworld.service");

// code to keep the service from being terminated
var keepAlive;
service.activityManager.create("keepAlive", function(activity) {
    keepAlive = activity;
});
service.activityManager.complete(keepAlive, function(activity) { 
    console.log("completed activity"); 
});

// hello command implementation
service.register("hello", function(message) {
    var response = message.respond({
        data: "Hello, " + message.payload.name + "!"
    });
});
```

It would be great if someone could give me some pointers.
As it is right now, I'm not getting any output whatsoever on the Node Profiler console.

Answer (score 1):

The way i did it ( i don't know if that's the only way)  to debug the code is through the chromium debugger eg. [image]

This is a generic image to see from where you are going to check the code.